# What are German words like Handy and Homeoffice called?

Tags: single-word-request, terminology, anglicism, pseudo-anglicism

There are some words in German which sound as if they were English foreign words, but have a completely different meaning in English, e.g.:

> Handy – mobile phone
>
> Homeoffice – Working from Home

This is different from false friends, because they are new recently created words and, such as in the case of *Handy,* many Germans think that it is just English.

Links to lists of such words are welcome as well.

BTW: the German *Homeoffice* has the synonyms *Telearbeit* and *Heimarbeit.*

Comment: "home office" (with a space) is a valid english word though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_office/home_office

Comment: I reject your premise that these are not [false friends](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falscher_Freund). "Es handelt sich hierbei um Paare von Wörtern oder Ausdrücken aus zwei Sprachen, die orthografisch oder phonetisch ähnlich sind, jedoch unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben. [...] Dabei können die Wörter entweder ursprungsverwandt sein, sich aber verschieden entwickelt haben [...], oder eine rein zufällige Ähnlichkeit aufweisen." Suits to a T.

Comment: @RegDwight In any case they would be a special subclass and `the situation is different`. The native speaker is not aware, that the foreigner might misunderstand him, because he thinks it is a known foreign word.

Comment: @RegDwight: Zu Handy ist allenfalls **handy** ähnlich, welches **handlich** bedeuttet. Was zu **home office** der false friend sein soll, darüber rätsel ich noch.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wikipedia calls them "pseudo-anglicisms" and has a [long list of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-anglicism) from a number of different languages.

Answer (score 17):

I don't know if there is a linguistic term for it, but I would call it `pseudoenglische Wortschöpfung` or simply `Pseudoenglisch`.

Another term in German is `Scheinanglizismus`, a sub-term of what German linguistics call *[Pseudoentlehnungen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoentlehnung)*.

Other examples:

- Showmaster
- Talkmaster
- Oldtimer
- Body bag (eigentlich: Leichensack)

Comment: Another term is *Dinglisch* which is a fword created from the two words *Deutsch* and *Englisch*

Comment: @FUZxxl: We call it normally *Denglisch*, with an e.

Comment: @swegi: I've heared both. It's not that there is a final authority on whether it is *Denglish* or *Dinglish*.

Comment: _Neudeutsch_ is another euphemism for English/German mashups

Comment: @FUZxxl: According to Google and Wikipedia, there is.

Comment: another lovely example is "Beamer" ^^

Comment: Another example I can think of seems to be pan-European, appearing in at least a few languages: "camping" to mean "campground".

Comment: +1 for "Oldtimer" which I really hate. @ladybug: what is "Beamer"?

Comment: It's an LCD projector. ;)

Comment: @hippietrail: 'appearing in at least a few languages: "camping" to mean "campground"' - not in German, though. The word "Camping" in German denotes the *activity* of staying on a campground, whereas the campground itself would be called "Campingplatz".

Answer (score 4):

here are a few more:

- Evergreen. english: a tree that is also green in winter. german: an old song that is still widely known.
- Beamer: a projector (idk: does this word exist in English?)
- public viewing. english: presenting the corpse of a deceased. german: TV in public places (sometimes using a beamer ehm projector)

an essay on the topic, which lists a few more examples: http://www.vds-ev.de/textbeitraege/729-text-blockbuster .
The site also has a huge index of anglicisms, but has no special index for the misleading ones.

a bb thread on the subject: https://de.pokerstrategy.com/forum/thread.php?threadid=984028 includes the hint to google for "false friends".

Comment: This does not answer the question. Btw, a BMW is colloquially called a beamer (possibly with different spelling).

Comment: @CarstenS, I thought so, too, but the question states "Links to lists of such words are welcome as well."

Comment: @Iris and Titus, ah, ok.

Comment: On the other hand, Evergreen is no pseudo-anglizismus (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/evergreen?q=evergreen) and beamer and public viewing are already listed in the long wikipedia list in the answer of trema. And the pokerstategy-link is just a unstructrured forum in German.